# Why are two elements with same coordinates in a d3-group not 100% overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

well I have kind of a strange problem. Two elements with same coordinates in a d3-group are not exactly overlapping. Under Chrome (1. pic) both coordinates x & y are off and under Safari (2. pic) x is off. On the pics you see only the text and the border of the textarea!
Does anyone know why and how to fix it (without manually adjusting the coordinates)?
First I add a svg to HTML-body, then a group to svg, then a rect to the group and then a textarea. Here some code parts:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 600')
.attr('width', '100%')
.attr('height', '100%')

grp = svg.append("g")
    .datum({x: 0, y: 0})

rect = grp.append("rect")
    .data([{x: data.x, y: data.y, width: data.w, height: data.h}])
    .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
    .attr('y', function (d) {return d.y;})
    .attr('width', function (d) {return d.width;})
    .attr('height', function (d) {return d.height;})

textarea = grp.append("foreignObject")
    .data([{x: data.x, y: data.y, width: data.w, height: data.h}])
    .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
    .attr('y', function (d) {return d.y;})
    .attr('width', function (d) {return d.width;})
    .attr('height', function (d) {return d.height;})
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
    .append('textarea')
    .style("width", (data.w) + "px")
    .style("height", (data.h)+ "px")
```

Chrome
[image]

Safari
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `<body>` and `<textArea>` elements inside your `<foreignObject>` has default CSS margins.

```js
var data = {x:20, y:50, w: 500, h:300}
var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 600')
.attr('width', '100%')
.attr('height', '100%')

grp = svg.append("g")
    .datum({x: 0, y: 0})

rect = grp.append("rect")
    .data([{x: data.x, y: data.y, width: data.w, height: data.h}])
    .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
    .attr('y', function (d) {return d.y;})
    .attr('width', function (d) {return d.width;})
    .attr('height', function (d) {return d.height;})
    .attr('fill', '#FF00FF'); // should be visible

textarea = grp.append("foreignObject")
    .data([{x: data.x, y: data.y, width: data.w, height: data.h}])
    .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
    .attr('y', function (d) {return d.y;})
    .attr('width', function (d) {return d.width;})
    .attr('height', function (d) {return d.height;})
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .attr('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
    .append('textarea')
    .style("width", (data.w) + "px")
    .style("height", (data.h)+ "px")
```

```css
foreignObject > body,
foreignObject textArea{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  border:0px;
  }
foreignObject body{
  background: transparent;
  }
foreignObject textArea{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5));
  }
body{
  background: lightsalmon;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Kaiido. The margin... of course. I did add "* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}" should work for all elements, I hope.